# Swift Long Delay Between viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm encountering an problem where I am having a long delay when trying to present a `ViewController`. I am trying to display an upgrade alert when a user clicks on a `UITableViewCell` which requires premium access. In the `ViewController` being presented, I put debug code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("\(NSDate()) viewDidLoad")
    // Set Navigation Title font and color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "UbuntuCondensed-Regular", size: 22)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    println("\(NSDate()) end of viewDidLoad")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("\(NSDate()) before super.viewWillAppear(animated)")
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    println("\(NSDate()) after super.viewWillAppear(animated)")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("\(NSDate()) before super.viewDidAppear(animated)")
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    println("\(NSDate()) after super.viewDidAppear(animated)")
}
```

The `println` statement resulted in:

```
2015-06-23 16:36:54 +0000 viewDidLoad
2015-06-23 16:36:54 +0000 end of viewDidLoad
2015-06-23 16:36:57 +0000 before super.viewWillAppear(animated)
2015-06-23 16:36:57 +0000 after super.viewWillAppear(animated)
2015-06-23 16:36:58 +0000 before super.viewDidAppear(animated)
2015-06-23 16:36:58 +0000 after super.viewDidAppear(animated)
```

As you can see there is a 3 second delay between the end of `viewDidLoad` and the start of `viewWillAppear`. I can't figure out why this is occurring. I am creating the views programmatically within the `ViewController`, so the storyboard is not being used here.

This is the code I have to present my `ViewController`:

```
// Create the upgrade view contorller
let upgradeVC = UpgradeViewController()
// Set the presentation context
self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
self.definesPresentationContext = true
// Set the upgrade controller to be modal over current context
upgradeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
// Show the view controller
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(upgradeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Are you creating and presenting the view controller on a background thread? You need to do that on the main thread.

Comment: I thought I was performing on the main thread. I created the `ViewController` within the function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. Once I surrounded the creating and presenting of the `ViewController` with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` it sped things up much faster. Would you be able to post your help so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: @MikeWalker i've also seen this on `tableViewDidSelectAtRow` only. This is a bug in swift I think

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating and presenting the view controller should be done on the main thread.

(When view updates are delayed, it nearly always means you're erroneously working on a background thread.)

Comment: Identical problem as Mike, and what's weird is that the view controller is presented while on the main thread (in the tableView:didSelect... method). Asyncing the presentation removes the 3 seconds delay.

Comment: @johnnyMac either (1) the UI work is going off he main thread at some point, or (2) something is blocking the main thread. You may have some kind of temporary locking issue (for example, if both the master and detail controllers are accessing the same resource).

Comment: That's the weird thing, apparently none of that is happening. I was thinking that the main thread might be blocked by something but verified that it's not - saw that in the time profiler. There is no activity on main for those 3 seconds. viewDidLoad ends, 3 seconds pass, then viewWillAppear is called.

Answer (score 2):

I am putting this out there so people understand the `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` time delay is nothing you did wrong if you are in `UITableViewController` `didSelectRowAt`.

There is clearly a hidden `async` `await` background thread bug inside Swifts `UITableViewController` `didSelectRowAt` callback:

If your code looks something like this it may well lag 2 or 3 seconds in between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`

```
class ViewControllerList: UITableViewController{
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)       
   {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Display", bundle:nil)
        let displayView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerDisplay") as! ViewControllerDisplay
        self.present(displayView, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

(despite you doing nothing to deserve it)

this is how you speed it up in Swift 4

```
class ViewControllerList: UITableViewController{
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)       
   {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // Background Thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Run UI Updates or call completion block
                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Display", bundle:nil)
                let displayView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerDisplay") as! ViewControllerDisplay
                self.present(displayView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I found that this issue only seems to happen when you present view controllers as modals (which made it extra confusing to debug). I would give more votes if I could, thank you.